# How to embed excel in word programmatically?

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba, ms-word

Are there any way to do so? I prefer to use VB.NET or Java and try to avoid to use VBA. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This information](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/amrish_deep/WordAutomation05102007223934PM/WordAutomation.aspx) might help. It walks through automating Word using C#, but the examples should get you going with VB.